# 4in6 tunneling (via OpenVPN?)

Tags: vpn, openvpn, ipv6, ipv4

I have a local network with internet access. But unfortunately IPv4 internet connection speed is limited to 1mbps, which is realy sad. Fortunately **I have a native IPv6**, and there is no connection speed limit over IPv6.

So, in order to get a good internet connection I made a plan: connect to the VPN-service over IPv6, and pass all IPv4 traffic through IPv6 tunnel, or something like that, I think you get the idea.

I suggested to use service like HideMyAss.com, but unfortunately they don't support IPv6.

The question is: Is there any existing VPN service that will make my dreams come true, and is easy to use, which I could connect over PPTP or OpenVPN (I want to set up connection to VPN in my router settings).

**Edit**: It seems like there are couple of VPN services that supports IPv6 (it's odd, but the biggest VPN services support only IPv4), and there is none providing 4in6 tunnels.

So, I came to the following solution: **rent a VPS with IPv6 address, and manually setup 4in6 tunnel.**

I'm not good at networking, never did things like that, and don't know where to start, and what should I do.

The use case, as I undestand, should look like this: I connect from my home computer to the VPS via OpenVPN, and after that all my IPv4 traffic pass through IPv6 (server do the job). OpenVPN - because I want to configure VPN connection to server in my router (Asus RT-N16?).
How can I achieve this?

Comment: Please add more info about your network architecture & modem and especially where do you have IPv6 and where not.

Comment: @harrymc what details are required? My ISP natively supports IPv6. I also have static IP addresses. Any specific router can be bought if needed.

Comment: See my answer. Additional useful info: Your operating system, computer model, and whether your connection is simply computer-router-ISP.

Comment: I have deleted my old answer and added a new one, hoping that it better answers the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is simple.

1. Set up a VPS with IPv6 connectivity and set up OpenVPN using a TAP interface (as opposed to TUN) on both the VPS and your local machine. Make sure you are connecting to the VPS over IPv6.
2. Make sure the TAP interfaces on both ends have private IPv4 addresses on the same subnet. Ping the VPS's private IPv4 address to make sure you have a connection.
3. Enable IPv4 forwarding and NAT masquerading on the VPS: `echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward`, `iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE`
4. On your local machine, delete the **default** IPv4 route: `ip -4 route del default`
5. Add a new default IPv4 route on your local machine, using the VPS's private IPv4 address as the gateway: `ip -4 route add default via 10.20.30.1` (assuming 10.20.30.1 is the IP address on the VPS's TAP interface)

I used this process (but in reverse) to get a IPv6 connection before my ISP provided one. [EDIS GmbH](http://www.edis.at/en/home/) offers cheap VPS with an IPv6 address in various countries. They have a multitude of options and Linux flavors to install as well.

Answer (score 1):

A virtual server approach will require lots of fiddling, actually setting up a cloud
computer hosted on a provider that supports IPv6.
While such providers exist, I'm not convinced that VPS is the only solution.

It seems to me that you require a cloud [Tunnel broker](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tunnel_broker) provider that provides
"IPv4 over IPv6", using your router's IPv6 capabilities to connect to that service.
That is, using an IPv6 router you would like to access IPv4 networks.

Unfortunately, most tunnel brokers give the opposite service of "IPv6 over IPv4",
for people having IPv4 routers but needing to access IPv6 networks.

Some useful info is contained in the Wikipedia article
[List of IPv6 tunnel brokers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_IPv6_tunnel_brokers), where you should be looking for providers
that support [4in6](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/4in6) and [Tunnel Setup Protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tunnel_Setup_Protocol) (TSP).

One likely candidate is [Freenet6](http://www.gogo6.com/main) and their free service [Freenet6 DS-lite (Beta)](http://www.gogo6.com/freenet6/dslite).
I have no experience with it and the documentation is sparse, but you could try and see
if it is useful. I do not know the bandwidth of this free service or if a faster
commercial service is available. You would have to contact their Support for that.

[SIXXS](http://www.sixxs.net/) seems like another good candidate.

Answer (score 0):

You're (potentially) on the right track with an OpenVPN and VPS type solution. The part you're likely missing is a route statement in the OpenVPN config to force it to take all IPv4 traffic.

Try this config option: http://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/howto.html#redirect

Answer (score 0):

Deshene, I believe you are somewhat confused.

The internet protocol is part of the internet layer of the TCP/IP model, who's cousin is the network layer of the OSI model. Its job is to get packets from A to B.

It has nothing to do w/ bandwidth. Bandwidth limitations are part of the physical layer(s) of those models. 'IPv4' if you will can (theoretically) 'handle' any bandwidth, b/c it's not part of the physical layer(s). Take a glance at most articles on the 'net about IP6, you'll see it was primarily formed to address the problem of more internet connected devices and therefore less and less IPv4 addresses available to those devices. More detail is beyond the scope of this answer but http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6.

You will not see a performance boost with this approach, guaranteed. You might even take a performance hit by adding hops into your route [more info](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teredo_tunneling). My recommendation is to look to your ISP for more bandwidth (whomever provides your uplink, since that's your bottleneck), make sure your network is capable of 1Gbps or better (which means all nics, switches, and network cable also).

Comment: As far as I understood, the poster's ISP bridles IPv4 more than IPv6, but I might be wrong.